# How to use a python application (tkinter).exe to open a text file

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

im a beginner at python and im trying to created a program using tkinter that view and edit text. i used pyinstaller to make an .exe file to view text, but when i used "open with" to a text file and select my text viewer program nothing shows.

then i noticed that how is my program supposed to open the file and display its contents. because originally i have this button "open file" that when clicked it, it will ask me what to open, but now that opening the file comes first before the program runs, i cannot click the button so my program does not know what to do. is there any way for my program to know what am i trying to open? do i have to import something?

thanks for the answer

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root=Tk()

def openfile():
    textname=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=(("Text", "*.txt"), ("Python", "*.py"), ("Html", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    openedfile=open(textname,'r')
    content=openedfile.read()
    n_text.insert(END,content)
    openedfile.close()


n_text=Text(root, font=11, relief=FLAT)
n_text.pack()
btn=Button(root, text="open", command=openfile).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use the full file path to the txt file.

Comment: thanks but the program suppose to open different files as a text viewer and editor, i can definitely use the full path like you said but i dont know how will my program suppose to get the path or directory of the file that im trying to open. and im trying to run the program as a standalone executable so manually changing the path everytime is not an option

Comment: you need to post the code using the edit question. Post the full script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question well. Do you need to know the path of the file you are opening?

```
    from os.path import split

    textname=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=(("Text", "*.txt"), ("Python", "*.py"), ("Html", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    pathname = split(textname)
    #This print is just to show your path and filename
    print("path:", pathname[0], "file:",pathname[1])
```

Based on your comments I add a new answer it take the full path from arguments on scripts.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

root=Tk()

def openfile():
    textname=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=(("Text", "*.txt"), ("Python", "*.py"), ("Html", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    openedfile=open(textname,'r')
    content=openedfile.read()
    n_text.insert(END,content)
    openedfile.close()


n_text=Text(root, font=11, relief=FLAT)
n_text.pack()
btn=Button(root, text="open", command=openfile).pack()

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    openedfile=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
    content=openedfile.read()
    n_text.insert(END,content)
    openedfile.close()

root.mainloop()
```

I added the path in this format:

c:/Users/user/Python/pruebas.py "C:\Users\user\Desktop\text_file.txt"

Comment: basically i turned that program to .exe using pyinstaller and tried to open a textfile by using "open with" when you right click the textfile in windows explorer. what happens is when my program opens but blank.

Comment: my question is how do i open that text file via "open with" in windows explorer and the contents with it. because whats happening is after the programs opens i still need to click the button "open" and find the file for the contents of the text file to actually show

Comment: I added a new version using sys.argv to take arguments from the command line. Check if it's what you want